# SoapUI: Property transfer is null

Tags: soap, properties, null, automation, soapui

[image]

I have Groovy Script:

```
lastName = stringDate+" "+lastName
```

And, I want to transfer `lastName` to `Req1` via property transfer. But, every time its shows `null`. Groovy Script works fine. I have problem during the transfer.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done without using property transfer as well. In the groovy script,

`context.testCase.setPropertyValue('LASTNAME',stringDate+" "+lastName)` and access it in the request step as `${#TestCase#LASTNAME}`